# How to redirect a webpage with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my htaccess but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
RewriteRule viewtopic\.php?t=([^/]+)$
http://newdomain.com/viewtopic.php?t=$1
```

How to redirect the page of viewtopic.php?t=1 to viewtopic.php?t=2000 to my new domain?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `.` and `?` in the pattern.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule viewtopic\.php\?t=([^/]+)$ http://newdomain.com/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Did you add the [L,R=301] after the RewriteRule? Also, in your question, you substitute `t=1`for `t=2000`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daniel Gehriger's solution, add `[L,R=301]` at the end of the line. This will make Apache send the 301 Page Moved code to your client, informing it that the page has indeed moved permanently. This will cause search engines, RSS readers etc update their links (if they are clever enough).

Answer (score 0):

just incase someone here have problem as mine, i use this  code to redirect an html page to a sub domain:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule sharecrypt.html http://cryptool.sharepirate.com [L,R=301]
```